# Where does openBSD store the IP address?

Tags: openbsd

I have an openBSD firewall, and I would really like to know in which file the IP adress of the firewall is stored.

And also where can I see if it set up to be with static IP or dhcp?

*Edit by pauska: Dont pack your /etc and put it on public hosting, it contains encrypted passwords and other info that could easily make you a target for hackers.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for each interface: `/etc/hostname.<if>` e.g. if the interface is em0, the file is `/etc/hostname.em0`

If the IP address is obtained via DHCP, there is only `dhcp` in it, else the address, network mask and options

[Maunal page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=hostname.if&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html) for this.

Update: if you want to set you IP address, just create the files. The /etc you provided doesn't contain any configuration of a "real" machine (no network, no ip adresses etc.) It lookslike a generic installer template ([flashrd](http://www.nmedia.net/flashrd/) is mentioned, although I haven't used it yet)

Comment: It is very strange. I don't have any files that starts with `hostname`. I have updated the question with a link to the content of `/etc`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That really helped me out. I would have expected that flashrd configured the interfaces. I am pretty sure I did set them at install time...?

Comment: I'm only familiar with the standard installer and some crude manually-putting-it-on-a-cf-card back then when cf cards were 64mb.

Comment: If the installer did not recognise a network card, it will happily install OpenBSD without reference to a network card (i.e. there is no /etc/hostname.*) Where this is the case, you can use `dmesg' after you've installed a network card (or boot the OS on a new machine with a network card.) Using the information of the 'network card' from dmesg, you can then create your own /etc/hostname.* file. For example: dmesg may tell you it identified a network card bge0. You can now configure /etc/hostname.bge0 to store configuration for that NIC.